# Microphone is not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I'm using **Lenovo ideapad 320-15ISK** and dual booting Ubuntu preinstalled windows 10 home.

- I selected **minimal installation** option.
- The microphone works fine in windows.
- Microphone does not work in "Try Ubuntu" either (tried in 18.04 also).
- Increasing the 'dB' brings noise.
- Sometimes the noise comes by itself without increasing the dB, times its dead silence.

It kinda works when I disable one microphone but after some seconds the disabled microphone automatically turns on itself.

Comment: Does the microphone work in the LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from your installer media again.

Select the "Try Ubuntu" environment.

Test your microphone in the "Try Ubuntu" environment.

- If your microphone works, then reinstall. DON'T choose minimal.
- If your microphone fails to work, then it's a kernel or hardware issue. Try again using a newer release of Ubuntu (newer kernel).
- If your microphone fails to work in the "Try Ubuntu" environment of the latest release of Ubuntu, AND you can demonstrate that you microphone works properly in other Linux releases or other operating systems, then please file a bug report.
- If your microphone fails to work under any operating system, then you likely have faulty hardware.

Comment: no, already tryed it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Your question seem incomplete and not clarifying the exact issue that you having. But Here are some way to Solve Your Problem.

1. Install the pavucontrol which is a tool that is for managing the Pulse Audio sound server on Linux.

   sudo apt install pavucontrol

After installing, Open it and there are 5 menus where you've to go to the **Input Devices** menu and check if it is not muted.

2. Second Method is on your system itself which is sounds. Simply open **Settings** and go to **Sound** tab and scroll down to **Input** Section and See the **Volumes** are increased or not, If Not then increase by your preference and check it if your issue got solved or not.

Comment: I already tryed it.